# Ansible Checks - OS version & Copy module

Tags: ansible

I wrote this playbook in order to check some functionality :

```
---
- name: install packages
  hosts: web
  remote_user: ansibleuser
  become: yes
  vars_files: vars/packages2

  tasks:
  - name: install packages
    yum:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      state: "{{ item.state }}"
    with_items: "{{ packages }}"
    when: (ansible_facts['os_family'] == "RedHat" and ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == 8)

  - name: start and enable services
    service:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      state: "{{ item.state }}"
      enabled: "{{ item.enabled }}"
    loop: "{{ services }}"

  - name: check os
    debug:
      msg: >
        Host {{ ansible_hostname }} does not meet minimal reqs
      when: ansible_distribution.RedHat is not defined

  - name: write to a file
    copy:
      content: This is a TEST FILE
      dest: index.html
  - name: copy to webserver
    copy:
      src: index.html
      dest: /var/www/html/index.html
      register: results
  - name: report an error on file copy
    fail:
      msg: "The html page is not copied!"
    when: results.rc !=0
```

I have 2 issues:

1. When the playbook starts to run , the following code is executed :

   ```
    - name: check os
    debug:
      msg: >
        Host {{ ansible_hostname }} does not meet minimal reqs
      when: ansible_distribution.RedHat is not defined
   ```

and the the message **"Host client2 does not meet minimal reqs"** is echoed , though it shouldn't because the managed node is RedHat.

2. It generates the following error :

   ```
       TASK [report an error on file copy] 
      fatal: [client2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 
      'results.rc !=0' failed. The error was: 
      error while evaluating conditional (results.rc !=0): 'results' is 
      undefined\n\nThe error appears to 
       be in '/home/ansibleuser/base/play9loop.yml': line 40, column 5, but 
         may\nbe elsewhere in the file 
      depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears 
   to be:\n\n      register: 
     results\n  - name: report an error on file copy\n    ^ here\n"}
   ```

which is related to the variable : **results**.
Any ideas ?

Comment: At what point do you define the variable `ansible_distribution.RedHat` that you query? If you haven't it's not surprising that the script does what you tell it to do. :)

Comment: The ansible_distribution.RedHat is actually an Ansible Fact , from there i retrieve that piece of information

Comment: I haven't tried with a RedHat server specifically, but I don't see why your example should work: the variable `ansible_distribution` has a string value corresponding to the operating system; the operating system is not an attribute of the variable. Try replacing your `when` line with this: `when: "'RedHat' not in ansible_distribution"`.

Comment: Yes ,it worked , thanks! Could you please take a look about the 2nd issue ?

Comment: The second issue is irrelevant: if a task fails you will get notified by design. 
If you do want to check a specific value, try debugging the variable (`result` in this case) and see what it contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See suggested changes and code review comments.

```
---
# Play names should reflect what it really does, not just one generic task name
- name: web server
  hosts: web
  remote_user: ansibleuser
  become: yes
  vars_files: vars/packages2

  tasks:
  - name: Check os is EL8
    assert:
      that:
      # Careful with os_family, Fedora is also "RedHat" but a much larger major version number
      - ansible_facts['os_family'] == "RedHat"
      - ansible_facts['distribution_major_version'] == 8
      fail_msg: Host {{ ansible_hostname }} does not meet minimal reqs
  
  - name: install packages
    # Using the generic package module wrapper allows for other OSes to be used
    #   although it does not translate package names
    package:
      # package transactions are more efficient when a list is passed to name
      # Rewrote loop to filter remove and install into two transactions
      #   TODO: Simplify.  Currently this requires every package to have "name" and "state" attributes 
      name: "{{ packages | selectattr('state', 'equalto', item) | map(attribute='name')  }}"
      state: "{{ item }}"
    loop:
    - absent
    - present
    # Deleted the when on package install:
    #  1. unnecessary with earlier assert
    #  2. RedHat is not defined is not the correct test

  - name: start and enable services
    service:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      state: "{{ item.state }}"
      enabled: "{{ item.enabled }}"
    loop: "{{ services }}"

 
  - name: copy to webserver
    copy:
      # A temporary file task is not needed for copy: content
      #  indeed, that is the entire point of the weird content parameter
      content: This is a TEST FILE
      dest: /var/www/html/index.html
      register: results
  
  # Extra reporting of file copy error is not necessary
  # Module failure will automatically be reported with a verbose message
  # For checking failure, use the test:
  # {{ results is failed }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input !  The 1st issue is clear.  Regarding the 2nd what I was trying to do is to generate a message whenever the file (index,html) failed to copied to destination server (managed node) . Is it feasible somehow to be done ?

Comment: @VorX Ansible will already fail with an appropriate message in that case. Which is what the comment is all about.

Comment: ok, got it ! thank you both !